# Feign Client Response not converting to objects

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-cloud-feign

I am calling a service and trying to store the response in a list of objects.

```
@FeignClient(name = "service")
public interface ServiceClient {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/url",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  @ApiOperation(value = "process")
  List<MyClass> select(@RequestBody String query);
}
```

The response returned by feign client is this

```
[
    {
        "segmentId": "Source_2021-09-01_2021-10-01",
        "columns": [
            "merchantRefNum",
            "customerId",
            "firstName",
        ],
        "events": [
            {
                "merchantRefNum": "67456456",
                "customerId": rfgvkhbj,
                "firstName": "peter",
            },
            {
                "merchantRefNum": "654584856",
                "customerId": null,
                "firstName": "peter"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My corresponding class is

```
class MyClass {
        private String segmentId;
        private List<String> columns;
        private List<Map<String, String>> events;
    }
```

I am able to convert using object mapper to verify my class and json like this

```
List<MyClass> responses = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString,
    new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

But when I am calling feign client and try to store response it gives me error

```
List<MyClass> responses = Service.select(query);
```

```
feign.FeignException$BadRequest: status 400 reading Service#select(String)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:92)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:86)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:93)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:149)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78)
    at f.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
```

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: This error is not a transformation problem on your client. You are invoking the API on the service but it's responding with an HTTP 400 Bad Request. You need to fix your parameters to conform with the API requirements (maybe you're missing parameters).